# Avoid if statement in class member function based on constructor inputs?

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, polymorphism

I'm looking for ways to optimize some ray tracing code that I have.  Say I have the following `Triangle` class such as the following (simplified for brevity):

```
class Triangle {
public:
    Triangle(Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, bool smoothShading);

    void intersect(Ray& ray)
    {
        if (smoothShading) {
            ray.hit.n = normalize(ray.hit.uv[0] * v1.normal + ray.hit.uv[1] * v2.normal + w * v0.normal);
        }
        else {
            ray.hit.n = -n;
        };
    };

private:
    bool smoothShading;
    Vertex<Tp> v0{};
    Vertex<Tp> v1{};
    Vertex<Tp> v2{};

    vec3<Tp> n;
}
```

`intersect()` member function needs to be called billions of times, and so I figure evaluating `if (smoothShading)` every time is completely unnecessary given it is known when the `Triangle` is constructed whether the value is `true` or `false`.  The simplest solution would be to have separate `SmoothTriangle` and `FlatTriangle` classes such that I could do:

```
void SmoothTriangle::intersect(Ray& ray)
{
    ray.hit.n = normalize(ray.hit.uv[0] * v1.normal + ray.hit.uv[1] * v2.normal + w * v0.normal);
};

void FlatTriangle::intersect(Ray& ray)
{
    ray.hit.n = -n;
};
```

The issue is that I'd then need to deal with references/pointers for this to work, but many of my functions expect inputs such as `std::vector<Triangle>`.  I could turn this into `std::vector<shared_ptr<Triangle>>` or something similar, but then I'd be introducing another pointer indirection, no?

In all of these cases, the member data actually contained by the various classes would be the same.  I just want the `intersect()` function to change based on how its been constructed, to avoid checking things when rendering, as while rendering many functions are called billions of times.

Comment: Just replace the whole `if/else` with `ray.hit.n =  ((smoothShading) * normalize(ray.hit.uv[0] * v1.normal + ray.hit.uv[1] * v2.normal + w * v0.normal)) + ((!smoothShading) * (-n));` which seem to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Basically, the trick is `(boolValue* trueValue) + (!boolValue * falseValue)`

Comment: branch prediction is rather good these days. I would not expect too much difference between your code and code that avoids the branch when taking into account that its always the same branch that is taken

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `if` statement is likely optimal.
The cost of performing a single `bool` check and branching is relatively trivial.
The cost in memory is significantly lower than dealing with polymorphic classes that can be `FlatTriangle` or `SmoothTriangle`, and also lower than having to store a function pointer.

Also remember that modern CPUs can predict branches. If lots of triangles are smooth or flat consecutively, this branch gets predicted and is virtually free.
**In any case, you should profile to make sure the branch is actually a problem!**

However, two bits of advice that may benefit performance:

### 1. Improve memory layout

```cpp
Vertex<Tp> v[3];
Vertex<Tp> n;
bool smoothShading;
```

This kind of layout is likely better.
Firstly, it's useful to have the vertices as an array so that you can access them by index if need be.
Secondly, the `smoothShading` member is not as important as the rest.
The later a data member appears in the class layout, the more likely it is to get spilled into memory when you run out of registers.

It would also introduce padding (likely 3 or 7 bytes) between `smoothShading` and `v`, and trailing padding is somewhat more convenient for compiler optimizations than gaps.

### 2. Avoid mutation, avoid aliasing, return objects

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct vec3 { float x, y, z; };

struct triangle {
    vec3 v[3];
    vec3 n;
};

void inc_normal_1(triangle& t) {
    t.n.x++;
    t.n.y++;
    t.n.z++;
}

vec3 inc_normal_2(const triangle& t) {
    return {t.n.x + 1, t.n.y + 1, t.n.z + 1};
}
```

[The emitted assembly for `inc_normal_2`](https://godbolt.org/z/oEG81x6j6) is somewhat simpler.
If you're not using the return type to return stuff, you may have to interact with memory more than with registers, which is slower.

You can also prevent optimizations further down the line because you introduce more aliasing.
A new returned object can never alias function parameters or global objects, and aliasing can prevent countless optimizations.

Of course, if the definition of `inc_normal_1` is visible and it gets inlined, this shouldn't be a problem, but that is not guaranteed to happen.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm not sure I follow the second half about returning an object.  By that I mean I'm following the snippet you shared, but it FEELS like it runs counter to what I was taught.  And it isn't immediately obvious to me when to return a new object versus just updating a reference to an object passed in.  I'm also a bit surprised that the compiler was unable to optimize those two to be the same, but then again I don't really understand compiler optimization

Comment: @ChrisGnam in this case, it's mostly a calling conventions thing. Some registers are being used for the return object of a function call, so you might not touch memory at all when `return`ing some small object. In this case, the result ends up in `xmm0` and `xmm1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could isolate the behaviors into separate class member functions, and then use a pointer to the desired function, eg:

```
class Triangle {
public:
    Triangle(Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, bool smoothShading)
    {
        ...
        if (smoothShading)
            m_intersect = &Triangle::interceptSmooth;
        else
            m_intersect = &Triangle::intersectFlat;
    }

    void intersect(Ray& ray)
    {
        (this->*m_intersect)(ray);
    }

private:

    void (Triangle::*m_intersect)(Ray&);

    Vertex<Tp> v0{};
    Vertex<Tp> v1{};
    Vertex<Tp> v2{};

    vec3<Tp> n;

    void intersectSmooth(Ray& ray)
    {
        ray.hit.n = normalize(ray.hit.uv[0] * v1.normal + ray.hit.uv[1] * v2.normal + w * v0.normal);
    }

    void intersectFlat(Ray& ray)
    {
        ray.hit.n = -n;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is almost certainly worse than OP's original code. The member function pointer is going to be at least 8 bytes on a 64-bit architecture, and assuming `Tp` is `float`, you've made the class 4 bytes larger. You're also adding an indirect call to whatever `m_intersect` is which cannot possibly be inlined. The calling overhead is likely much greater than an (easily predicted) branch.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to use the following trick inside `intersect` as shown below:

```
class Triangle {
public:
    Triangle(Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, bool smoothShading);

    void intersect(Ray& ray)
    {
            //no need for if else anymore here
            ray.hit.n =  ((smoothShading) * normalize(ray.hit.uv[0] * v1.normal + ray.hit.uv[1] * v2.normal + w * v0.normal)) 
                         + ((!smoothShading) * (-n));
        
        
    }
//other code as before
};
```

Comment: This is almost certainly slower than OP's original code. Assuming the `bool` is in a register, OP's code just requires one cycle to `test` it and one cycle to `jmp`. With branch prediction and out-of-order execution, the if statement might be basically free. You're introducing numerous floating point operations (just multiplying with `-n` is three floating point multiplications), each of which are 5 cycles latency.